# Pandas Interpolate not giving what I expected

Tags: pandas

I have a table that looks like this (note: TransactionDate is the index):

```
               GroupByFld | Amount
 TransactionDate 
 2014-03-31    | 1        | -0.000 
 2014-04-30    | 1        | nan 
 2014-05-31    | 1        | nan 
 2014-06-30    | 1        | -122129.805 
 2014-07-31    | 1        | nan 
 2014-08-31    | 1        | nan 
 2014-09-30    | 1        | -100553.145
```

I'm interpolating it and I get this:

```
               GroupByFld | Amount
 TransactionDate 
 2014-03-31    | 1        | -0.000 
 2014-04-30    | 1        | -73277.883
 2014-05-31    | 1        | -36638.942
 2014-06-30    | 1        | -122129.805 
 2014-07-31    | 1        | -12212.981
 2014-08-31    | 1        | 326146.968
 2014-09-30    | 1        | -100553.145
```

The code I'm using to do this is as follows. Note because my GroupByFld contains both 1 and 2, I'm filering on it so that I can apply the interpolation to each one separately. For debugging purposes I've restricted the df to contain just 1's but still got the same issue.

```
for i in range(len(c['GroupByFld'].unique())):  # This will break if there are multiple group by criteria
      mask = c.loc[:,'GroupByFld']==c['GroupByFld'].unique()[i]
      c[mask]=c[mask].interpolate(method='linear')
```

Comment: Look at this line `c.loc[:,'GroupByFld']==c['GroupByFld'].unique()[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Ok answer may seem obvious to some but it's actually not documented anywhere from what I could see.

I assumed that just by setting my index to a date, it would automatically know how to order the data. Instead I had to first force it to sort in the right order using:

```
c.sort_index(inplace=True)
```